# Need to do an order by before the query runs

Tags: mysql

The query works, but I need it to do `order by g1.caller , g1.created_on` first. The reason being is I need to compare callers in succession, so I can see if they had to call multiple times to get an issue resolved.

```
SELECT 
    g1.caller,
    g1.created_on,
    g1.config_item,
    g2.caller,
    g2.created_on,
    g2.config_item
FROM
    smp_newcall g1
        INNER JOIN
    smp_newcall g2 ON g2.id = g1.id + 1    
WHERE
    g1.caller = g2.caller and    
    g1.config_item = g2.config_item and
    g1.created_on between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
```

Bonus points if you can get `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,date(g1.created_on),date(g2.created_on)) > 48` to work in the where statement. Currently it returns 0 for some reason. The column is set to datetime.

The expected return data should be any caller, that has multiple tickets logged within a 48 hour period for the same config_item.

```
Row 1: John Smith, 2017-07-01 10:00:00, Outlook, John Smith, 2017-07-01 11:00:00, Outlook
Row 2: John Smith, 2017-07-02 11:00:00, Outlook, John Smith, 2017-07-03 11:00:00, Outlook
```

Once I am done validating though, it will just return counts. For now I want to see yes, the same person within 48 hours and it was for the same thing.

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d696/1
Now that I know the data is sorted, I have another problem. It is missing 2 returns. It should also return:

```
john doe 2017-07-01T11:00:00Z Windows 7 john doe 2017-07-02T10:00:00Z Windows 7 
john smith 2017-07-01T11:00:00Z Outlook  john smith 2017-07-02T10:00:00Z Outlook
```

Comment: Add some sample data and sample expected results please.

Comment: Done. The reason I need this sorted, is because comparing previous rows won't work. We get callers in between and it can span across multiple days.

Comment: Any chance we can get a table schema of smp_newcall and a couple sample rows?  Any unique identifiers for caller and config_item (to avoid cases of multiple John Smith's)?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SQL Fiddle added. Now that you mention it I will need to use their lan id as a unique modifier instead of their name.

Answer (score 0):

IMO There is no need to pre-sorting. Comparisons between adjacent rows are easier in programs than in queries. Or even you might use user-defined variables, but seems like you can start a new approach from here:

```
SELECT g1.caller
     , g1.config_item
     , count(1)
  FROM smp_newcall g1
  WHERE g1.created_on between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
    AND exists( SELECT 1
                  FROM smp_newcall g2
                  WHERE g2.caller = g1.caller
                    AND g2.config_item = g1.config_item
                    AND g2.created_on >= g1.created_on -interval 48 hour 
                    AND g2.created_on < g1.created_on
              )
  GROUP BY g1.caller
         , g1.config_item
```